# How can I handle with ICollection in a model and database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, icollection

I have to store data in a Database using a model

My models :

```
public class Poste
{
        public int Id { set; get; }

        public string intitule_poste { set; get; }

        public ICollection<Candidat> candidats { get; set; }
}


public class Candidat
{
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public List<Poste> postes {set;get;}
}
```

so  that  generate  another table (using EF )  called   PostesCandidats

that  have

```
PosteId   CandidatId
```

My  question  is :  how can  I  use  that  List  (Icollection )    to  store  data in  PostesCandidats table?

For Exemple  i want  to store a candidat  and give  him  a  poste

Comment: depends on how you store your other data

Comment: You 'just' add your new `Poste` object to the collection `postes` of a candidate. That EF stores it in an extra table is an implementation detail.

Comment: oh!!!! I will try that  if  it  works  for  me  i will love EF  always  =D

Comment: For an example refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First

Comment: it works great!!  but  the problem that  my  postes  table  is a fix  table  that  have  4  postes (static )   i  dont  want it to be chenged ......but  when i save chage it create another poste in my table tha have  Id=5  (for exemple )..for me i want  jast  PostesCandidats table to be changed